# How to call block after particular action is finished?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have boolean parameter BOOL isMoving. 
I want to set this parameter to FALSE after particular action finishes running.
My code looks like this:

```
CCActionMoveTo* actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:[self GetPosition]];
CCActionCallBlock* blockUpdate = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{isMoving= FALSE;}];
CCActionCallFunc* actionCallFunction = [CCActionCallFunc actionWithTarget:nil selector:@selector(accessDelegate:)];
CCActionSequence* seq = [CCActionSequence actions:actionMove,blockUpdate,actionCallFunction, nil];
[self runAction:seq];
```

unfortunately neither blockUpdate  nor actionCallFunction waits till actionMove is finished.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both blockUpdate and actionCallFunction **do** wait for actionMove to finish with the code you provided.

The only explanation I can offer is that a move action that moves to the same location the node is currently at is simply ignored, since the node "is already there". Your use of [self GetPosition] seems to indicate that the move action moves the node to its current location:

```
CCActionMoveTo* actionMove = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0f position:[self GetPosition]];
```

If that is not the case try replacing the move action with a CCActionDelay action to just wait for n seconds.

Comment: I have set action duration to 5.0f to slowly monitor action, and this action happens, it slowly moves object. I'm using parameter isMoving  to check during touch handling, if it is set to TRUE I should return without doing nothing, i.e it means that object is still moving. So 5 sec is good time to monitor everything, object is is moving and it also touch is processed. Another thing, how I found out that selector accessDelegate is also performed, I set break point in that method, while 5 sec action is in progress application stops at break point imidiately

Comment: I have new findings, It' strange but blockUpdate  waits for action to finish but actionCallFunction does not. But it is ok for me, I can do my task with block, thanks